# How can I get username and name of active local changes from git project in IntelliJ plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I would like to create a plugin that would use a username and name of active local changes in git project. Can I get this information from action or context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

For git username:

```
private static String getGitUsername() {
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("git config user.name");
        process.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        return reader.readLine();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return DEFAULT_USER;
    }
}
```

For name of active local changes:

```
private static String getChangeListName(Project project) {
    return ChangeListManager.getInstance(project).getDefaultListName();
}
```